# Model return NULL trying Pass values of Selected checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view with a number of checkboxes in it. I want to be able to pass the values of the checkboxes to the controller by Serialize form, but my Model return `NULL` and it cant quit catch checkbox value from view to controller.
Can anyone please help me or point me into right direction ! :)

Here is the View:

```
@model CreateCustomers

<form id="CustomerNEmployeeForm">

   @{ 
        var newGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

 <input type="hidden" name="RightsCodes.Index" value='@newGuid' />
 <div><input type="checkbox" name="[@newGuid].RightsCodes.OpenOrders" value="true" class="checkbox-template"><label for="checkboxCustom1">Åbne ordrer</label></div>
 <div><input type="checkbox" name="[@newGuid].RightsCodes.ClosedOrders" value="true" class="checkbox-template"><label for="checkboxCustom1">Lukkede ordrer</label></div>
 <div><input type="checkbox" name="[@newGuid].RightsCodes.Deliveries" value="true" class="checkbox-template"><label for="checkboxCustom1">Leverancer</label></div>
 <div><input type="checkbox" name="[@newGuid].RightsCodes.RMA" value="true" class="checkbox-template"><label for="checkboxCustom1">RMA</label></div>
 <div><input type="checkbox" name="[@newGuid].RightsCodes.SellingPrices" value="true" class="checkbox-template"><label for="checkboxCustom1">Se salgspriser</label></div>
 <div><input type="checkbox" name="[@newGuid].RightsCodes.FullAccess" value="true" class="checkbox-template"><label for="checkboxCustom1">Fuld adgang</label></div>
 <div><input type="checkbox" name="[@newGuid].RightsCodes.UserAdmin" value="true" class="checkbox-template"><label for="checkboxCustom1">User admin</label></div>

</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function CreateCustomerNEmployees() {

      var formdata = $("#CustomerNEmployeeForm").serializeArray();

       $.ajax({
                "url": '@Url.Action("CreateCustomers", "User")',
                "method": "POST",
                "data": formdata ,
                "dataType": "json",
                complete: function () {
                    console.log('Ok');
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
                }

            });
    }

</script>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CreateCustomers
    {
  public RightCodes RightsCodes { get; set; }
  public class RightCodes
        {
            public bool OpenOrders { get; set; }
            public bool ClosedOrders { get; set; }
            public bool RMA { get; set; }
            public bool Deliveries { get; set; }
            public bool SellingPrices { get; set; }
            public bool UserAdmin { get; set; }
            public bool FullAccess { get; set; }

            public List<string> Trues()
            {
                var results = new List<string>();
                if (OpenOrders)
                    results.Add("Åbne ordrer");
                if (ClosedOrders)
                    results.Add("Lukkede ordrer");
                if (RMA)
                    results.Add("RMA");
                if (Deliveries)
                    results.Add("Leverancer");
                if (SellingPrices)
                    results.Add("Se salgspriser");
                if (UserAdmin)
                    results.Add("User Admin");
                if (FullAccess)
                    results.Add("Fuld adgang");
                return results;
            }
        }

   }
```

Controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult CreateCustomers(List<CreateCustomers> model)
        {
             var resultsThree = new List<Rights>();
             foreach (var item in model)
              {

                foreach (var right in item.RightsCodes.Trues())
                {
                    var RettighederInsert = new Rights
                    {
                        //PX2ID = px2id,
                        Rettighedskode = right,
                        IsChecked = true

                    };

                    db.Rights.Add(RettighederInsert);
                }
              }

            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       }
```

Output after serialising :

```
0: {name: "RightsCodes.Index", value: "45f57034-0e99-402c-bcf4-1d28ac1e50fd"}
1: {name: "[45f57034-0e99-402c-bcf4-1d28ac1e50fd].RightsCodes.OpenOrders", value: "true"}
```

Comment: Are you getting values after serialising?

Comment: try with public JsonResult CreateCustomers([FromData]CreateCustomers[] model)

Comment: @NijinKoderi Yes im getting value after Serializing